# UIView's subviews rendering outside bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I have created a nib for a view in interface builder. Its subviews are placed with constraints such that they will scale with the size of the view's frame.

I use a helper method to initialize the view from its nib:

```
+ (TinyTestResultsView *)ttrView {
    TinyTestResultsView *ttrV = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TinyTestResultsViewNib" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
    [ttrV commonInit];
    return ttrV;
}
```

During a view controller's `viewDidLoad`, I initialize the object using the `ttrView` method and add it as a subview to `self.view`. The VC then makes a call to the network to get some information, and then adds constraints as necessary to `self.view` and the subview to place it. It gets correctly placed & sized - however the view appears as a white box with no subviews. **Why are the subviews being rendered outside the view?**

If I use Debug View Hierarchy in Xcode and then try to find the subviews, I see that they are being rendered way outside the frame, and they are not complying with the autolayout rules from the NIB. I am using this exact same technique for a different custom UIView/nib, so I'm not sure what could be happening incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` for your view. When you load view from Nib file in such way this property is set to `YES` that means the system creates a set of constraints that duplicate the behavior specified by the view’s autoresizing mask. And this is not what you want when you use autolayout.

Comment: I have `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` in `commonInit`

Comment: Don't you have warnings related to constraints in nib file for this view?

Comment: Try to [look](http://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Screen-Shot-2015-09-05-at-1.39.09-PM.png) at preview in nib file(if you haven't done this yet). Do views have correct layout?

Comment: No constraint conflicts, and the preview renders as it should.

Comment: Thanks for your help @curious. During the refresh I was removing all of the view's constraints, not realizing that those really affect its subviews, not just the view itself. Fixed it.